# ProgramData folder issues - where do I put example files in .NET Setup Project?

Tags: c#, .net, deployment

I've been using XML files in the folder:
C:\ProgramData\CompanyName\AppName

to hold settings.  My application has no problem reading and writing the settings file in that folder via the (C#.NET) XmlDocument object.

Recently I wanted to add some example datasets to my deployment and placed them in the folder:
C:\ProgramData\CompanyName\AppName\ExampleData

However, when trying to access files in this folder via BinaryReader (C#.NET) I'm getting a "System.UnauthorizedAccessException".

How is the XmlDocument able to read from ProgramData and yet a BinaryReader can't?  Should I do something different when trying to read?

Alternatively, what friendly/findable folder should I use for example datasets?

Comment: Usually, the files in ProgramData have read access for all authenticated users, write access to administrators. But of course, your setup may have decided to override these permissions. Did you check the permissions of the file in question in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

It requires authorization when accessing the ProgramData folder.

As a solution, you can run the application as an administrator. Or, you can use the Appdata folder. Appdata folder address is as in the example, you can share your file to this path, you can solve the access error:

```
//Sample path: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming
var appdataPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData);
```

Comment: Thanks.  I'm still curious as to why does the XmlDocument class have access without issues?

Comment: I will research this issue and let you know. @MarkMalburg

Comment: I've also found that the .NET 4.6 app built by Visual Studio 2015 can access the folder, but when I build in Visual Studio 2022 (same project) I cannot access the folder.

Comment: I wonder if the project gives the same result when compiled? @MarkMalburg